# From nested JSON to table with rowspan Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I tried to make a table with my nested JSON get from an api. I don't know how to dynamically merge my cells when necessary knowing that my JSON can be nested up to 6 or 7 times.

What I want :
**Table I want**
[image: Table I want]

What I got :
**Table I got**
[image: Table I got]

My TS file :

```
 questionnaire = [
    {
      title : "theme1",
      children : [{
      title : "theme2",
         children : [
         {
           title : "theme3",
           children : []
         },
         {
           title : "theme4",
           children : []
         },
       ]
     }]
   },
   {
     title : "theme5",
     children : [
       {
         title : "theme6",
         children : []
       },
       {
         title : "theme7",
         children : []
       },
     ]
   },
 ]
```

My component.html :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let periode of questionnaire">
    <br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>{{ periode.title }}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let theme of periode.children">
          {{ theme.title }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: @evolutionxbox he said it's a TS file ...

Comment: In the posted array you sometimes use `titre` instead of `title` as the key

Comment: Yes, I fix it, it's `title`

Answer (score 0):

Generating your tables via a recursive function and then setting the restulting HTML via `[innerHTML]` would be a good call.

The recursive function would need not only return its corresponding HTML part of the table but also how many rows it contains. That way you can utilise the `rowspan` Attribute whenever there are children.